# Mod_rewrite and $_GET variables

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, get

If I am mod_rewriting a URL from:

http://www.mysite.com/blog/this-is-my-title/1/

to

http://www.mysite.com/blog.php?title=this-is-my-title&id=1

...is it possible then to arbitrarily attach a get value on to the URL later, or does the mod_rewrite throw it off?

MY REWRITE RULE:

```
RewriteRule    ^blog/([A-Za-z]+)/(0-9]+)/?    blog?title=$1&id=$2     [L]
```

EXAMPLE:

can i go
http://www.mysite.com/blog/this-is-my-title/1/?first=Johnnie&last=Wiggles

which would essentially mean

http://www.mysite.com/blog.php?title=this-is-my-title&id=1&first=Johnnie&last=Wiggles

I would think that should work, but for some reason it's not for me at the moment.

Comment: Can't answer this without looking at your RewriteRule.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add QSA to the `RewriteRule` flags:

```
RewriteRule page_([0-9]+)\.html page.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Will redirect `page_1.html?a=2` to `page.php?id=1&a=2`

However, be careful because requesting `page_1.html?id=2` will redirect to `page.php?id=1&id=2`, and (in PHP), `$_GET['id']` will be 2.

Comment: Here's a link to the documentation on QSA: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to append it, with the QSA (query string append) flag.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule {from-url} {to-url} [L,NC,QSA]
```