# mod_rewrite passing variables

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have the following mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ search.php?action=procedure&procedureName=$1
```

This works fine in redirecting things like /blabla to /search.php?action=procedure&procedureName=blabla

The problem is that sometimes I want to pass a 'start' value (for pagination). For example, /blabla/?start=20.

Currently, it just ignores it. Printing out the $_REQUEST array doesn't show 'start'. I tried modifying the rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/\?start=([0-9]+)$ search.php?action=procedure&procedureName=$1&start=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ search.php?action=procedure&procedureName=$1
```

But it didn't do anything.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mod_rewrite and $_GET variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498966/mod-rewrite-and-get-variables)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ search.php?action=procedure&procedureName=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

The `QSA` means query string append, and it'll append $_GET vars you pass. Otherwise, they are normally not added.

Answer (score 2):

RewriteRule applies to the path. You need to use RewriteCond to match the query string.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Or to just pass the query string through, use %{QUERY_STRING}

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ search.php?action=procedure&procedureName=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think I found my answer:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ search.php?action=procedure&procedureName=$1 [QSA]
```

The QSA allows it to pass query strings.
Right?