# How to keep original parameters after url_rewrite?

Tags: http, get, url-rewriting

I'm now doing this:

```
 rewriterule ^jobs/([0-9]+)/.* job.php?id=$1
```

Which will erase parameters in jobs/1010/title?k=v

How to keep them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mod_rewrite passing variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597794/mod-rewrite-passing-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More of a serverfault question, but... Append the [QSA] flag:

```
rewriterule ^jobs/([0-9]+)/.* job.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

From the docs for [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> 'qsappend|QSA' (query string append)
>
> This flag forces the rewrite engine to append a query string part of the substitution string to the existing string, instead of replacing it. Use this when you want to add more data to the query string via a rewrite rule.