# How make this htaccess redirect correctly

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect this urls using `htaccess RewriteRule`:

```
news/tags/video to news.php?t=video
news/tags/interview to news.php?t=interview
news/tags/news to news.php?t=news
```

the urls: `news.php?t=video, news.php?t=interview, news.php?t=news` are working fine and I recive the "t" var correctly. But when I apply `htaccess RewriteRules` the "t" var is not passed.

This is my code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #this rules are working fine
    RewriteRule ^news[/]?$ news.php
    RewriteRule ^news/(.+)[/]?$ news_article.php?idN=$1

    #problem rules
    RewriteRule ^news/tags/video[/]?$ news.php?t=video
    RewriteRule ^news/tags/interview[/]?$ news.php?t=interview
    RewriteRule ^news/tags/news[/]?$ news.php?t=news
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597794/mod-rewrite-passing-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrites are handled in order of matching. If other rules exist that return true first your redirect states will likely not be matched. In your case a match was being found prior to reaching your additional rules.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteRule ^news/tags/([^/]+)/?$ news.php?t=$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^news[/]?$ news.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)[/]?$ news_article.php?idN=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `^news/(.+)[/]?$` matches `news/tags/video` (etc) and rewrites the URL to `news_article.php` and no further matching is possible. You need to tweak this rule just a little:

```
RewriteRule ^news/?$ news.php
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/?$ news_article.php?idN=$1
RewriteRule ^news/tags/video/?$ news.php?t=video
RewriteRule ^news/tags/interview/?$ news.php?t=interview
RewriteRule ^news/tags/news/?$ news.php?t=news
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change this `RewriteRule` directive on your code:

```
RewriteRule ^news/(.+)[/]?$ news_article.php?idN=$1
```

... to this one:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)[/]?$ /news_article.php?idN=$1
```

Because the previous rule matches everything, including *"/"* slash. And just use this single rule below as the solution on your `#problem rules`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/tags/([^/]+)[/]?$ /$1.php?t=$2
```