# htaccess redirect add querystring

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm triying to redirect `www.myweb.com to www.myweb.com/?lang=en`
Any try i made redirect all the traffic in the website or creates a loop.
Any help?

Comment: could you update your question with the relevant content of your **.htaccess** file please :)

Answer (score 1):

I thinkg it should be easier for you to set the GET variable lang to 'en' in php, rather than redirecting... In your code, before handling the lang variable, try:

```
if (!isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $_GET['lang'] = 'en;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it via a rewrite rule for whatever reason, this worked for the simple example I tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?lang=en [QSA]
```

Though there are similar questions on stack overflow you should check out: [ModRewite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498966/mod-rewrite-and-get-variables) and general searching ;)